# Emulating a shell environment

Tags: environments

I'm trying to define a new environment, which emulates a shell. The way I would like to use it:

```
\begin{shell}
\item{echo foo}{foo}
\item{echo bar}{bar}
\end{shell}
```

Which should produce:

```
This is my shell prompt
1> echo foo
foo
2> echo bar
bar
```

What I have so far:

```
\newcommand{shellprompt}{This is my shell prompt}
\newenvironment{shell}{
  \shellprompt
  \begin{enumerate}[\hspace{15px} 1\textgreater]
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand\item{\olditem}
  }{
  \end{enumerate}
}
```

How do I redefine the `\item` command so it accepts a second parameter and prints it on a second line?

**Bonus**: How do I wrap everything (prompt + items) in a `verbatim` environment?

Comment: Why `\item`? You can define your own custom macro with any number of arguments, instead of redefining a macro already used by latex for other purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{shell}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\%\{\},formatcom=\setcounter{prompt}{0}}
\newcounter{prompt}
\newcommand{\prompt}{\stepcounter{prompt}\theprompt>}

\begin{document}
\begin{shell}
%prompt echo foo
foo
%prompt echo bar
bar
\end{shell}
\end{document}
```

In the shell command you'll need to escape `%`, `{` and `}` with a `%`, so, to print

```
% { }
```

you have to input

```
%% %{ %}
```

[image]

If you want to add the same first line to all environments,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{shell}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\%\{\},formatcom=\setcounter{prompt}{0}\start}
\newcounter{prompt}
\newcommand{\prompt}{\stepcounter{prompt}\theprompt>}
\newcommand{\start}{\noindent This is my shell prompt\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{shell}
%prompt echo foo{}
foo
%prompt echo bar
bar
\end{shell}
\end{document}
```

Just redefine `\start` to suit.

Comment: Right. But what about the prompt used as "header" (the "This is my shell prompt" line shown only once for each shell environment)?

Comment: Awesome. I've also realized that the fancyvrb package supports labels, which for me represents a valid alternative for the "header". Thanks so much.

Comment: The start command trick doesn't work well when a frame is used in the environment.

Comment: @RobertoAloi No, it doesn't. :(